# Python program repeatedly executes infinite loop abnormally

Tags: python

I designed an input
A python program based on the sum of deposits for each day within 7 days
I hope the execution result is:

```
Please enter the deposit on day 1: 40
Please enter the deposit on day 2: 70
Please enter the deposit on day 3: 89
Please enter the 4th day deposit: 489
Please enter the 5th day deposit: 39
Please enter the deposit on day 6: 48
Please enter the 7th day deposit: 99
   Total deposit: 874 dollar
```

But the problem with my python program is
Circulate from the deposit on the first day to after the deposit on the seventh day
Unable to add up smoothly, but re-start the cycle from the first day of deposit
In an infinite loop
My code:

```
sum1=0
mes=list()
while True:
   for mes in range(1,8):
      mey=int(input(f"Please enter the deposit on day {mes}:"))
      if mes==7:
       break
       mes.append(mey)
       sum1+=mey
print("Total Deposit",str(mes),"dollar")
```

Comment: You should break again after the for loop.

Comment: For clarity do you want the total after entering the 7 days then ask for another 7 days before giving another total?

Comment: I want me to enter every day's deposit (7 days in total)
After the input, the loop is interrupted
Calculate the total deposit

Comment: You have two loops here. The `for` loop and the `while` loop. You have only one `break` statement. The `break` statement exits the for loop. Then goes back to the while loop and starts all over again. The code you have posted and the output you shared are not the same. Day 4, 5, and 7 code looks different. Also, why are you checking for `mes==7`, the for loop will exit once `mes` reaches 8. In summary, you just need the for loop. You can remove the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some problems I can see:

- You are re-declaring `mes` variable in the `for` loop; use another variable name
- the `while` loop is unnecessary
- the `break` is unnecessary, because the `for` loop will execute while `mes <= 7` (in this case the `break` will exit the `for` loop, and not the `while` loop)
- you should print the `sum1` variable at the end; the `str()` function is unnecessary

Your new code should look like this if we address the code issues as stated above.

```
sum1=0
mes=list()
for i in range(1,8):
    mey=int(input(f"Please enter the deposit on day {mes}:"))
    mes.append(mey)
    sum1+=mey
print("Total Deposit is",sum1,"dollar")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
total = 0
mes = []

for i in range(1,8):
    m = int(input(f"Please enter the deposit on day {i}: "))
    mes.append(m)
    total += m

print(f"Total Deposit {total} dollar.")
```